# tensorflow meet a warning "Gradients do not exist for variables"

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient

sorry I'm a beginner to tensorflow, when I tried to write a custom layer there was a warning '**Gradients do not exist for variables**' after call **model.fit()**

To illastrate my issues, here are my code:

```
class gen_noise_sig(layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self):
        super(gen_noise_sig, self).__init__()

        self.m = self.add_weight('m',[1],trainable=True).numpy()
        self.sig = self.add_weight('sig',[1],trainable=True).numpy()
    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            "m": self.m,
            "sig": self.sig,
        })
        return config

    def call(self, inputs, training = True):
        out = inputs + tf.random.normal(tf.shape(inputs),mean=self.m,stddev=self.sig)
        out = tf.expand_dims(out,axis=-1)
        return out


def AutoEncoder():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(gen_noise_sig())
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(8,strides = 5,kernel_size = 128,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu',name='encoder_input'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(16,strides = 5,kernel_size = 32,padding = 'same',activation = 'leaky_relu'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(32,strides = 5,kernel_size = 16,padding = 'same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(128,strides = 4,kernel_size = 4,padding = 'same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(128,strides = 2,kernel_size = 2,padding = 'same',name='encoder_output'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1DTranspose(128,strides = 2,kernel_size = 4,padding = 'same', name = 'decoder_input',activation='leaky_relu'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1DTranspose(32,strides = 4,kernel_size = 4,padding = 'same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1DTranspose(16,strides = 5,kernel_size = 64,padding = 'same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1DTranspose(8,strides = 5,kernel_size = 64,padding = 'same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1DTranspose(1,strides = 5,kernel_size = 64,padding = 'same',name = 'decoder_output'))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    return model

model = AutoEncoder()
model.build(input_shape= (None,10000))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mae',
              metrics=['mae']
)
# print(model.trainable_weights)
filepath = 'AutoEncoder/Denoising/Damage/CNN_AE_model1020.h5'
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
history = model.fit(targetData,
                    targetData,
                    batch_size=200,
                    epochs=1000,
                    validation_split = 0.1,
                    callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Can someone tell me why the gradients do not exist and how to solve this problem, please.

Comment: Your layer is not implemented correctly, why are you doing .numpy() in add_weight?

Comment: because I met with the error “Unable to serialize variables to JSON” when I tried to save checkpoints, and someone told me .numpy() might work, can you give me some advice？

Comment: No, you do not use .numpy() there because you need the tf.Variable that is returned by add_weight, and it produces the issue of not having gradients. You have a clear XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I might understand the issue.